# Dropdown buttons not clickable

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, dropdown

Ok this problem is very difficult to explain... i have a website with a portfolio and some of my buttons in my dropdown menu are unclickable. now i have found out whats making them unclickable and it is my graphics grid div.

some how the nested half divs are infront of the dropdown content but the content in the half divs are behind the dropown.

the buttons that are unclickable are FAQ and Privacy policy how ever if you hover your cursor in the center of the page on the dropdown the buttons are clickable and that is because there is a split down the middle of the page between the 2 halfs that are nested in a div. as i said this is hard to explain sorry if this gets confusing.

the issue is not happening in internet explorer but is happening in chrome.

here is my website with the issue: https://thg-graphics.com/portfolio.html

here is the code :

```html
 <div id="container">
      <div id="header" class="w3-center w3-opacity">
        <!-- Header start -->
        <h1>THG Graphics</h1>
        <h1 class="w3-xlarge">Graphic Designer</h1>
        <div class="w3-padding-32">
          <div class="border"><a title="Home" href="index.html" class="w3-button dropbtn">Home</a><a title="Portfolio" href="portfolio.html" class="w3-button w3-grey dropbtn">Portfolio</a><a title="Enquiry" href="Enquiry.html" alt="Enquiry" class="w3-button dropbtn">Enquiry</a>
            <div class="dropdown" style="float:right;">
              <button title="About" alt="About" class="w3-button dropdown dropbtn dropdownmobile">About</button>
              <div class="dropdown-content border" id="myDropdown">
                <a title="Contact us" href="Contact.html" alt="Contact us" class="w3-button">Contact us</a>
                <a title="Terms of use" href="TOS.html" alt="Terms of use" class="w3-button">Terms of use</a>
                <a title="Privacy policy" href="privacypolicy.html" alt="Privacy Policy" class=" w3-button">Privacy Policy</a>
                <a title="FAQ" href="FAQ.html" alt="FAQ" class="w3-button">FAQ</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <h2>Welcome to our Portfolio</h2>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Graphic Grid -->
      <div class="w3-row-padding" style="margin-bottom:128px">
        <div class="w3-half w3-center">
          <video controls height="380" width="512" class="video" poster="Images/thg.jpg" controlsList="nodownload noaudio">
            <source src="videos/Comp 1.mp4" type="video/mp4"> Your browser does not support the video tag.
          </video>
          <video controls height="380" width="512" class="video" poster="Images/Arff custom.jpg" controlsList="nodownload noaudio">
            <source src="videos/ARFF Custom 3_x264.mp4" type="video/mp4"> Your browser does not support the video tag.
          </video>
          <video controls height="380" width="512" class="video" poster="Images/bullet.jpg" controlsList="nodownload noaudio">
            <source src="videos/bullet fixed_x264.mp4" type="video/mp4"> Your browser does not support the video tag.
          </video>
    <video controls height="380" width="512" class="video" poster="Images/Rita.jpg" controlsList="nodownload noaudio">
            <source src="videos/Rita.mp4" type="video/mp4"> Your browser does not support the video tag.
          </video>
</div>
        <div class="w3-half w3-center">
          <video controls height="380" width="512" class="video" poster="Images/pot.jpg" controlsList="nodownload noaudio">
            <source src="videos/flower pot_x264.mp4" type="video/mp4"> Your browser does not support the video tag.
          </video>
          <video controls height="380" width="512" class="video" poster="Images/hello.jpg" controlsList="nodownload noaudio">
            <source src="videos/Hello_x264.mp4" type="video/mp4"> Your browser does not support the video tag.
          </video>
<video controls height="380" width="512" class="video" poster="Images/jarvis.jpg" controlsList="nodownload noaudio">
        <source src="videos/Jarvis_x264.mp4" type="video/mp4"> Your browser does not support the video tag.
          </video>
    <video controls height="380" width="512" class="video" poster="Images/THG Animation.jpg" controlsList="nodownload noaudio">
            <source src="videos/THG Animation.mp4" type="video/mp4"> Your browser does not support the video tag.
          </video>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="THG-center">
            <a title="Next" href="page-2.html" class="w3-button border">Next</a>
   <a href="portfolio.html" class="w3-button border w3-grey">1</a>
            <a href="page-2.html" class="w3-button border">2</a>
          </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: It's almost definitely a CSS `overflow` issue. Can you please post your CSS here as well, thus forming a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: not easily. its combined by w3.css and THG.css (THG is my css). they are both linked as seperate files in the coding.

https://thg-graphics.com/styles/THG.css <>
https://thg-graphics.com/styles/w3.css

Comment: @Sean Then only include the relevant parts of the `CSS`. Surely it won't be much or hard to find.

Comment: i did include it. https://thg-graphics.com/styles/THG.css thats my css not much in there. should be easy to find what you need but i am really struggling cos if i use z-index in hopes to fix it, it has no effect on it probably due to w3 schools stupid css..... it messes with alot of things lol. but its got something to do with my 2 halfs in my graphics grid those are what are causing this problem something to do with the 2 halfs.

Comment: It may be that your `video` divs are sitting on top of the header dropdown. Try adding `position: relative; z-index: 2;` to your `#header`style

Comment: @Sean By include the relevant `css` means within your question. Dumping a link means others have to fish through the `css` to find the relevant parts. If you take the time to copy the relevant parts and display them withing your question like you have with the `html` I'm sure someone will take the time to answer your question. Until then, I can't see many people willing to help if you aren't willing to spend the time to find the relevant parts of your `css`.

Comment: yeah well i dont know what the issue is therefor dont know what you need from my css so dumping it for you to look through is my only option atm cos i dont know what the issue is if your saying its css...